# How to transfer buildings and objects from one Minecraft world to another?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was playing mine craft on a friends account. I liked it so much I bought my own account. But now I want to transfer all the cool stuff I made from the random world on their account to my account.

How do I do this?

Comment: If you played with a friends account on your computer, the saved worlds should still be there when you switch accounts.  If you played on another computer, moving the saved worlds is easy to do.  Another option if you just want a few structures is [structure blocks](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Structure_Block).  They allow copying structures.  They can then be imported into another world.  [Here is a great tutorial](https://www.digminecraft.com/basic_recipes/make_structure_block.php) on using structure blocks to save and load structures.

Answer (score 2):

Worlds are not tied to accounts, but computers. On their computer, you will need to go to:

- In case you are using Windows: %appdata%/.minecraft/saves and copy your world to a flash drive, and put it in the same directory in your computer.
- In Linux the same folder can be found at: /home/< your Linux username >/saves

Answer (score 0):

On your friend's computer find your minecraft folder(On Windows type %appdata% then go to .minecraft, then to saves. On Mac open finder, then select the drop down menu Go, then click Library, then to Application Support, then to Minecraft,then to saves) Copy your world then have your friend email it to you or put it on a thumbdrive
Edit: You will need to do the same thing you did to find the save and put it in your saves folder on your own computer

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way I can think of would be to use a program like [MCEdit](http://www.mcedit.net/). Although im not sure if it will let you just copy and paste from one world to another. You might have to still recreate it, but using MCEdit will make the process a lot faster. Here's another link on [how to use MCEdit](https://www.howtogeek.com/203396/how-to-edit-your-minecraft-maps-with-an-external-editor/).

Comment: That's overkill. You just have to go to the saves folder and copy the world.

Comment: Possibly - I also read the question in the context he wanted specific *buldings* moved, not whole worlds.

Comment: @Fabian, yeah I guess that would effectively transfer the items. I read the question as the OP just wanted to copy their creations and not the whole world.